# Android Map v2 Drawing ellipse

Tags: android, android-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

How i can drawing ellipse in Google Map Android api 2? anyone knows how to draw it? i've been searching but there is no answer. i'll be thankfully for any help

Comment: what you are tring to do..???

Comment: drawing ellips shape,not circle

Answer (score 1):

I think as there is currently no `Ellipse` object or 'radius' method with two radius options inside `Circle` you have to use [Polyline](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline) and calculate the needed positions by yourself.

Comment: Or `Polygon` if you need to fill it.

Answer (score 0):

You can take an help of this [Working Example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_eshapes_ellipse_fromBounds.html), but this has been made in v3, u can do the same in v2 too